# Fedora installed on M.2 sata ssd storage is not showing up

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssd, fedora, grub

I installed an M.2 sata SSD (256GB) on my Dell vostro 5468 laptop. It detected fine in windows initially, and then I installed fedora on it. However after rebooting, I did not get a grub menu and also in Computer management in windows, the ssd only has 1 GB storage space empty, and I cannot see the partition where fedora is installed.
Also, I live booted Fedora again and it is also not showing the partition where fedora should be installed, and free space is shown to be 1GB just like windows. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does UEFI settings > Boot menu show a Fedora entry? If so select it, that's Grub.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your boot order in your UEFI BIOS configuration menu to where the SSD with Fedora on it is prioritized over the one with Windows.